# Database design for a web application

Tags: database, database-design, web-applications, database-schema

This is very much a noob question, so please bear with me.

Consider a web application with 100,000 users. Each user can create entries or blog posts, as you may call it. Assume each user has 100 entries. Would it be appropriate to store all the users in one table? (Meaning, a table with 100,000 rows?) and further have another table to store the entries made by each user.

Is this a bad design? What would be an efficient way to store all the information to facilitate quick access of the information?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That sounds fine - 100,000 rows in a table isn't really that many at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 100,000 rows is not a big number for a database table to handle - and separating the entries from the users is a good decision.

A simple structure would be something like:

```
User
  |
-----
| | |
Entry
```

User table

```
UserId
FullName
IsDeleted
```

Entry table

```
EntryId
UserId
EntryName
EntryContent
IsDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a basic [relational model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model), which is perfectly fine.

Whether 100.000 rows in a table is a good idea depends on various factors, such as what RDBMS you're using, what hardware it'll run on, how many queries per second you're expecting, et cetera.

Comment: Also, if you're not that familiar with database design principles, you should probably read up on topics like [foreign keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) and [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).